# Set transform value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I want to set the value:

```
translate(-50%, -50%) translate(-100px, -300px);
```

to transform css property of div tag.

I use the next command:

```
jQuery('.content').css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%) translate(-100px, -300px);');
```

But I see nothing changes. How can I set that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your jQuery code there is a semicolon `;` at the end of `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(-100px, -300px);` which prevents jQuery from using the code. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.